# WPF use the result of a binding as input string in XAML

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I need to get access to some strings from my VM (objects in a list on the VM) such that it could be used in the XAML as if it were hard coded strings.

I have made my own TranslateBinding class. The string provided as path is used as language lookup key in the TranslateBinding class. If the language lookupkey provided does not exist I would use the string entered in the FallBackValue.

Normal usecase with hardcoded key and fallback values

```
<TextBlock Text="{TranslateBinding 'thelookupkey', FallbackValue='Lookup Key Not Found'}" />
```

But now I need 'thelookupkey' string to be the value of a property. The same for the Fallback value.

So I would like to be able to do something like this

```
<TextBlock Text="{TranslateBinding {Binding LookupKey}, FallbackValue={Binding FallBackString}}" />
```

That is not working, so the question I have is. Can I somehow get the values from the LookupKey and the FallBackString properties as pure "resource strings" in my XAML in a way that I could use it for the TranslateBinding?

The reason I need this is because I want to use the TranslateBinding in a DataTemplate of a ComboBox, such that the translation is performed based on each Item's individual LookupKey and FallBackString properties.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your explanation. Have you considered a converter? By language lookup do you mean you are doing localisation with fallback values? I use dynamicresource for that. Have a base resource dictionary has strings for everything. Then merge in (say) French or Russian with same keys. It's common to retain many strings in English for say admin users. In which case the French or Russian resource dictionaries have a subset of values.

Comment: The TranslateBinding is just to give the context. The main question is how to bind to a string on an object in a List on the VM. Then being able to use that string as a Path to the translation binding.

I am thinking if one could setup a resource or similar. But if so how should it look like.

Comment: You would need to arrange things so the binding on the Text property is set in code. Since you want a binding you also need a dependency object from somewhere.  I'd consider an attached class and property to drive this. You can have a string dp on that and create a binding in code. The string you have from lookupkey would be used as the propertypath on the binding. You'd need another property of course for the fallbackvalue.

Comment: @Andy This sounds about what I am looking for and inline with the error messages. Can you guide me a bit further on how to create such attached class and property?
I realized I could not add another DependencyProperty to the TranslateBinding class since one would need to derive from a suitable base class then, and I am already inheringing from System.Windows.Data.Binding.

I believe the attached class and property you refer to is a way to work around that?

Comment: This is all theoretical so I'm guessing this will work.  This would be instead of translatebinding. The class would have at least 2 dp. You need one for the text representation of path and another for the result. Text binds to the latter. The attached class then creates a binding in code using the string as the propertypath.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by making use of

```
<PriorityBinding>
   <LocalizationBinding NameLookupKey .../>
   <Binding Name , FallBack='Missing Name'/>
</PriorityBinding>
```

It allowed me to try another binding if the first one failed.
I also made a LocalizationBinding class instead that used the value from the Property defined in the provided Path to do the language lookup.